# Auto completion function Java

Tags: java, autocomplete, compilation

I am working on a Displaykeyboard for disabled peaople and i am thinking about to adding a auto word completion function.
I found a example from oracle that works as i need it. Its the Another Example: TextAreaDemo. The problem is i dont really understand the search algorithm and the problem is when i add some word to the arraylist the search algorithm stops working properly.

```
String prefix = content.substring(w + 1).toLowerCase();
int n = Collections.binarySearch(words, prefix);
if (n < 0 && -n <= words.size()) {
    String match = words.get(-n - 1);
    if (match.startsWith(prefix)) {
        // A completion is found
        String completion = match.substring(pos - w);
        // We cannot modify Document from within notification,
        // so we submit a task that does the change later
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
        new CompletionTask(completion, pos + 1));
}
} else {
// Nothing found
mode = Mode.INSERT;
}
```

Is there a way to modify the example so it will work with any words?

Comment: Here the link to the example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html

Comment: `binarySearch` relies on sorted input, so I guess you don't sort your list again after adding a word?

Comment: the list will be static so this is not really needet

Comment: So you don't sort at all? Or do you add the words in sorted order?

Comment: dident knew the list must be sorted and i think this is the error? When i add the word sorted this will work properly? Is this a good solution for many words? to add them already sorted is no problem.

Comment: Not having a sorted list is _an_ error, so you should at least fix that. But you haven't posted a [MCVE], so no one can say definitively where the error is.

Comment: Jeah the problem was the not sorted list now it is working fine so thanks. Is the binary search reliable for long lists or should i tke something else?

Comment: Binary search is O(log(n)) which is pretty good. It's the sorting that takes longer, but that doesn't really matter since you only do it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're not just adding the word to the end of the list and then using `binarySearch()`. It's documentation says the following

> The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the natural
>   ordering of its elements (as by the sort(List) method) prior to making
>   this call.

Read more about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T)

Comment: Oh jeah thats the problem. Is binarySort capable to be used with many words?

Comment: Absolutely. The more words the longer it'll take to find a match but it should definitely be fast enough for what you're using it for